# Smart Contract Upgrade Patterns: Differences Between Strategy Pattern and Diamond Pattern

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts

I have been looking into Smart Contract upgrade patterns, my main source of information is: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/upgrading/. To me, the Strategy Pattern and the Diamond Pattern looks quite similar:

| Strategy Pattern | Diamond Pattern |
| --- | --- |
| Main contract | Proxy contract |
| Satellite contracts | Facets |

A slight difference between the two patterns is how they keep track of satellite/facets contracts. This is done using a mapping of facets in the Diamond pattern vs simply storing the satellite contract addresses in the Strategy pattern.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. Are there any other differences between these two patterns that I may have overlooked?
2. Is there an advantage over using one of these contracts over the other?